# How do I root my Alcatel 500r4?

Tags: rooting, alcatel

I own an Android Alcatel 5004r and am trying to root it. Does anyone have any suggestions

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on Software Recommendations site

Comment: @RohitGupta nope, questions about the procedure of rooting a specific device are perfectly on-topic here, although becoming more uncertain to be answered due to many possible factors.